# Cheap Hosting Provider for Business Splash Page?

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for a provider to host a splash page for my business.

One page (index.htm) with some basic HTML (company name, logo, contact details), and a CSS stylesheet. That's it.

It's mainly for reference (to complement business cards).

I also don't have a domain purchased yet (but the name is available)

What's the cheapest provider for this scenario? (if they also offer the DNS, bonus - two birds one stone).

As it's only one page, and no dynamic content - i obviously don't need a dedicated server, a VPS/shared server would be fine.

Cheapest/most well known seems to be GoDaddy.

Can anyone name/recommend a few more?

Answer (score 2):

[Heroku](http://heroku.com) or [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/). Both free, and really scalable if/when you need it. They're designed to deploy Ruby and Python/Java apps respectively, but even if you're not using one of those, you can easily host just static HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed Fat Cow has a $5 a year plan for just this purpose.

http://www.fatcow.com/fatcow/minimoo.bml

That gives you a single page, and email.

Answer (score 1):

HostGator offers shared cPanel hosting which would fit the bill starting at $4.95/mo - there will always be cheaper cPanel shared hosts, but I'd hesitate to recommend any of them because I've seen so many come and go. (or, in the case of midPhase, become highly unreliable and a real pain to work with)

Whether you have to switch hosts from time to time as a result of downtime or horrible support should *definitely* factor into the effective price of the host - the apparent price tag isn't always the real price tag after you factor in headaches and downtime.

GoDaddy may very well suit your present needs at a lower price, however, I've always been disappointed with their lack of functionality and configurability in comparison to a standard cPanel implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As i said, it's only 2 files - index.html and site.css. So i don't really need full control. There shouldn't need to be hardly any configuration (just chuck the files into the root, configure DNS, done). $4.95 pm is a little pricey for what i'm doing, i'll probably go with GoDaddy. Thanks.

Comment: Beware GoDaddy, they may seem cheap but EVERYTHING is an addon.  Also, consider your time trying to navigate their clunky UI.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider hosting it on a local computer and using a dynamic DNS service like [zoneedit](http://www.zoneedit.com/) provider to point your domain to it. It's free and you have full DNS control as well.

Answer (score 1):

A decently reliable/reputable web host usually costs about $9-10/month. So I don't think you're going to get a much lower monthly rate than danlefree's suggested HostGator plan.

Though I'd recommend just getting a standard $8.95 DreamHost account. You get unlimited nearly everything (domains, subdomains, MySQL databases, shell accounts, ftps, bandwidth, storage, etc.), and you get a free domain for the life of your account. A lot of web designers have single-page websites but still get this type of standard shared hosting account. It's only $4/month more and it gives you room to expand.

Also, be aware that, even though GoDaddy and HostGator offer super-economy hosting plans with slightly lower monthly rates, you could end up spending much more with them. For instance, if you need an SSL certificate, DreamHost sells them for $15/year. But GoDaddy charges $50/year and HostGator charges $150/year. DreamHost also offers free private domain registration, whereas GoDaddy and HostGator both charge $10 per domain extra for it.

Personally, I'd choose DreamHost just because they have higher standards of ethics than many of these others companies. (They don't work with domain squatters; they don't try to nickle-and-dime you; and they don't use your expired domains as their personal billboards).

Also, because DreamHost's basic hosting plans comes with pretty much unlimited everything and lets you create separate users for different domains, you could just share a hosting plan with a few friends or other local businesses. If you can find 4 other businesses that want cheap web hosting, you could each pay less than $2/month and still get a far better hosting plan than what you'd pay even $10-15/month for elsewhere.

Comment: He can google for "dreamhost coupons" and find coupons that take close to $100 off their hosting. That takes the cost below $2 a month.

Comment: @mellowsoon: that's only for the first year, but that's still a good point.

Comment: èse I have a love-hate relationship with Dreamhost, but you can't beat their prices for the number of features they give you. You're right. He could get 5 buddies together, and the hosting would be close to free!

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.qualityhostonline.com in US
- http://www.eukhost.com in EUROPE (server in UK)

I'm being happy with these two.

---

**UPDATE:**

**eukhost.com got worst and worst, continuous downtimes** I complained and also bought a more expensive plan so I should be supposed to get a better uptime, but nothing! I'm definitely gonna change and find a new webhoster in EU soon. The qualityhostonline.com is still superlative!