# Best cheap Linux hosting with LAMP support

Tags: web-hosting, linux, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for a linux hosting provider that supports LAMP and wondering if the community could recommend one.

I was thinking about going with godaddy since their plan is only like $5 / month, but was wondering if there any others out there that are just as cheap if not cheaper

Comment: Question should be closed, ther is no BEST. Similar questions are: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/investigating-and-finding-a-web-host/ and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/cheap-hosting-provider-for-business-splash-page/

Comment: @Marco - I notice you have plenty of rep - feel free to cast a close vote yourself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a firm believer in "you get what you pay for". However, I have been using Dreamhost for quite some time and I am very pleased. I also hear that A Small Orange (http://www.asmallorange.com/hosting/shared/) is really decent as well.

Ultimately it depends on your traffic and the hosts network capabilities to handle that traffic. Small sites should be fine on either of those hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if they use Linux but I think do and the site is http://www.freehostingcloud.com/ and theyy have free everyting and the only limit is that if you have over 2000+ unique vistors per month you have to pay USD$10 per month.

I have been using the free version for about 12 months now and have about 4 websites all of which are just of my software for my use.

Answer (score 0):

I have used www.awardspace.com out of Germany. I like them even though they had a serious problem earlier in the month.